# separating and supporting hyperplanes

Tags: functional-analysis

I am thinking about the following problem regarding the hyperplane separation theorem: If we have two disjoint non empty convex subsets (lets say $A$ nad $B$) of a normed space $X$, then there exists a nonzero vector $v$ and a real number $c$ such that\begin{equation}
\langle x,v \rangle \ > \ c \text{ and } \langle y,v \rangle \ < \ c \text{ for all } x \in A, y \in B.
\end{equation}
if either both sets $A$ and $B$ are open or $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact. Furthermore if $A$ is closed we can especially separate every point $x_0 \notin A$ strict from the set $A$ because $\{x_0\}$ is a compact set.
What we also know is that we can separate any two convex sets $A$ and $B$ in a weak sense, meaning \begin{equation}
\langle x,v \rangle \ \geq \ c \text{ and } \langle y,v \rangle \ \leq \ c \text{ for all } x \in A, y \in B,
\end{equation}
with the help of a supporting hyperplane. What I am thinking about now is the following: If we have two disjoint convex sets $A$ and $B$ and we know that one of them, lets say $A$, is closed and we do not know anything further about the set $B$. Is it then possible to separate the two sets in a way that at least one side is strict? I.e. in a way that \begin{equation}
\langle x,v \rangle \ > \ c \text{ and } \langle y,v \rangle \ \leq \ c \text{ for all } x \in A, y \in B.
\end{equation}
I think this should be possible because if we use supporting hyperplanes we can seprate every point outside $A$ strict from $A$ because $A$ is closed. But then it should be also possible to separate a convex set strict from $A$ by the help of a supporting hyperplane. Or am I wrong on this? I have tried to construct a separating hyperplane using supporting hyperplanes but unfortunately with no outcome so far. Has anyone an idea about this? Or can anybody say if my intuition is right?
Thanks a lot in advance!
Best, 
Chris

Comment: Use `$\langle\rangle$` for $\langle\rangle$.

Comment: You need some boundedness condition on $A$ or $B$, otherwise there will be counterexamples.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, take $A = \{(x,y) : y \ge e^x\}$ and $B = $ the $x$-axis.

Comment: @ fredgoodman: I think your point is, that you can not separate the x-Axis from $A$. And, to me this also seems to be right but wouldn't this contradict the fact, that we can separate any point on the x-axis from the set $A$ ?

Comment: @AfRo In your last paragraph, what do you mean by a convex set of points?  Any convex set is either a singleton or uncountable.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you are right, of course. I mean a convex set, not just a singleton. Changed it, thanks

Comment: But, as I said above, there are counterexamples without further assumptions, and fredgoodman gave one.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I was just wondering how this can be combined with the fact that, without further assumptions, one can separate any point on the x-axis strict from the set $A$ in fredgoodmans example. Just trying to understand it... and do you know what further assumptions are needed? does it only work in the case where the other set is compact or can this assumption be relaxed a bit when the separation should only be 'half-strict' ? Thanks for helping!